# angular-material, adding unique id to paginator next/previous buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using angular-material paginator component. It is working fine. My QA person want to test it by clicking next button in paginator, but there is no unique identifier for that in HTML. Is there any way to add ID to next/previous button?

Comment: There is a class? `mat-paginator-navigation-next` and `mat-paginator-navigation-previous`

Comment: Yes, he says it will be better if there is an Id

Comment: only one time used int per  page or more than on time?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.mat-paginator-navigation-previous').setAttribute('id', 'yourID')`